# sshd - How to block a list of IP addresses?

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd

I recently noticed a lot of failed ssh login attempts on my Centos 8 Stream workstation, I analyzed the logs and found over 300000 Failed login attempts from 9326 different IP addresses. I wonder how to block this long list of hosts, without disabling passwordAuthentication in sshd.conf.

I probably can't block a list of IPs using firewalld and I can't use /etc/hosts.deny file, becuase TCP Wrappers package is deprecated. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3906701

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Use fail2ban or some other blacklisting mechanism, and preferably only allow certain hosts to even SSH to your box by implementing firewall rules.

Comment: @cutrightjm Sweet, I will try to use fail2ban, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'd highly recommend changing the default `sshd` port. Not only it will save the hassle of blacklisting wide ranges of IP addresses (some of which you yourself can connect from whenever you travel), it will also pretty much free you from the torrent of failed login attempts. Using a port below 1024 is a good idea just to be sure that no local non-root applications can sneakily start listening instead.
2. Another excellent idea is to use `knockd` ( https://github.com/jvinet/knock ) which allows to open certain ports only if you knock the device properly by probing certain ports.